# Installing docopt fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install docopt using:

`pip install docopt`

and I receive the following error:

```
  Using cached docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  x python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ?─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-blasc4d8\docopt_56c5
acf1079d44219547b2dca2c4e6df\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
          from docopt import __version__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
      [end of output]
```

I am not sure why the installation of docopt imports itself. I would appreciate a solution to this issue. Note that I am using python 3.8.10 on Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/453

Comment: It seems the solution to my problem was to place `docopt.py` from github project into python directory then install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

1. Downloading the `whl` from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python-wheels/blob/master/wheelhouse/docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
2. Installing it with:

   ```
   python -m pip install docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   ```